# Using multiple methods in a transaction

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions

I'm making an Android app, which gets its information from XML files.
I'm filling the information in a database, for easier acces during the program's runtime, thanks to the power of queries.

However it came to my attention, that using Transactions greatly improves speed, so naturally, I want to use that.

My problem is the following tho;
In the idea of abstraction, after parsing all the information of *one* subject, the information gets send to the correct entity (class), and inside that entity there is a method that will add it in the database. After that, it returns to the parser which continues to read the next subject, which in it's turn will be send to right (and probably different) class again.

This is implemented with a switch statement, with every case pointing to a different class constructor.

If I want to use the speed of transactions, I would need to start a transaction already before the parsing, run through the parsing and query building (as far as I understand, all queries build within the transaction, are collected and in the end all executed as a bunch) and then end the transaction, once the whole file is parsed.

To make this a bit clearer, or faster to read; The code idea would be;

```
    Class parser(){
  database.beginTransaction();
    try{  
         // start parsing in a whole different class, which also points to SQL queries (in different classes again) in the entitys with a switch
       }catch(Exception e){
    database.endTransaction();
       }
        database.endTransaction();
}
```

I hope i formulated my question clearly enough.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've got the general idea. However, you need to be careful to mark the transaction as successful when you finish parsing, and also to ensure the transaction is always closed even in the event of an exception.

Example from [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29):

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // do all the parsing in here
    ...
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Hi Graham Borland,
Thanks for the quick reply.
The core of my question tho, is if it's no problem to start a, lets say 'general transaction' somewhere, and to have a lot of code in between the transaction. Most of the examples found, simply start a transaction, and instantly execute a query or at max loop through something, and then execute queries.

Comment: Per example, using exaggeration. The question would be, when per example making a program that only creates and fills a database.
I *could* start a transaction right at the main method, run the whole rest of the program while that transaction stays open, and then when everything is done, succes and end the transaction, finally executing all the queries build in the program at once.

I understand that this is of course exaggerated and not wanted.

Comment: There is no problem having the transaction open for the duration of a long-running XML parsing operation. It provides many benefits, including speed, as you noticed yourself.

Comment: Oke that's all I need to know, thanks :)
I can't give you're post +1 shamefully, because I don't have enough reputation.